# Increasing the size of an icon without increasing the text-size within that same button > (text + icon) > only increasing icon

Tags: css

This is the CSS code that I already have in place for the button. I want to increase the size of the icon inside of this button. How? (adding css to the wordpress pagesite). Thank you

```
.nectar-button.fixed-size-energy {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 290px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black,
                 2px 2px 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you please give us the HTML of the button and icon as well? In any case it should be an easy fix, like just adding .nectar-button i{ font-size: 30px; }

Answer (score 0):

If your icon is inside of your button, you can create CSS rule that only targets that icon, inside of the button:

```
.nectar-button i{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```